# How do I adjust this "hidden" door hinge?

Tags: doors, hinges, gap

How do I adjust this type of hidden door hinge so that the hinge part on the door itself gets closer to the hinge part on the door frame? I figure it's done using the two top and bottom hex screws on the door side hinge, but no matter how I screw or unscrew them the difference is unnoticeable.

It's the Italian brand Nusco.

[image: Picture 1]

I need to do this because the upper part of the door has a bigger gap when closed, as you see below, and creaking occurs.

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Just to be clear, are you turning the pozidrive screws or the hex screws?

Comment: The hex ones. Which directions should I turn to tighten the gap?

Comment: I'd try counter clockwise on all 4. (Upper hinge.) They might possibly not be conventionally threaded as much as move through a range of adjustment when spun 360 degrees.

Comment: it looks like the left side of the hinge has a depth adjustment